# Optimal Strategy Question

Tags: probability

Someone asked me this question a while ago and I'm not sure how to go about it:

> Suppose two players are playing a game. The first player  chose an
>   integer between 1-30. The second player picks a different one. After
>   that, a random integer (x) between 1-30 will be generated with uniform distribution. The player
>   whose number is closer to x gets paid x dollars. What number should you pick if you go first?

My gut tells me it's 15 but since there is more weighting on the payoff for larger values it should be larger than that. Apparently the optimal strategy is to choose 22. What is the best way to approach this question?

Comment: Just calculate the expected value as a function of $x$. Do you know how to calculate the probability, after the player has chosen the value of $x$?

Comment: You need to specify the distribution that the random integer $x$ will have. The natural assumption is a uniform distribution, but for completeness, you should write that down (if the assumption is indeed correct).

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377393/30-sided-die-2-player-game?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is: what do we mean by "should" in "what number should we pick"? The best strategy depends on what the other player will do. I'll assume that the second player is self-interested and rational, so they'll always pick the strategy which gives them the best outcome. I'll also assume that what we care about here is average gain, so "best" means maximizing expected profit.

If the first player chooses $a$ and the second player chooses $b$, then their expected profits are determined and we can calculate them. For each $a$ there then exists a $b$ which maximizes player two's profit, and we can compute player one's profit given those choices. We then choose the $a$ that maximizes that value.

The full calculation is a little tedious and I don't feel like working out the fine print right now. I did a sketch of it below and got the wrong answer ($21$ rather than $22$), but it illustrates the process and shows where the number $22$ comes from.

---

So for the choices $a$, $b$, the expected profits are roughly:

$$\frac{N+\frac{b+a}2}2\frac{N-\frac{b+a}2}N=\frac{N^2-m^2}{2N}$$

for whoever picks the highest number, and

$$\frac{\frac{b+a}2}2\frac{\frac{b+a}2}N=\frac{m^2}{2N}$$

for whoever picks the lowest number, where $N=30$ and $m=\frac{b+a}2$.

So suppose we pick $a$. From the above formulae you can see that your opponent's best move is going to be to pick either $a+1$ or $a-1$, depending on which one gives them the most profit. Working out the inequality, we'll obtain that $a+1$ is the superior choice precisely when $a^2\leq\frac{N^2-\frac12}2$, that is when $a\leq21.2$.

By the same logic which shows that player two's best bet is to pick either $a+1$ or $a-1$, we can immediately conclude that our best first move is to pick either $21$ or $22$. In either case we will have $m=21.5$. When we work out which of the two possibilities gives us the higher expected profit, we actually get $21$, not $22$.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this, is to calculate the expected profit after the event $x$ has occured.

An intuitive explantation why 22 is the optimal strategy goes as follows. Say you play this game a lot of times ($n$), and you always choose 22. If the other player chooses a number lower than yours, say 21, he will win when the number is lower than 22. You will win if the number is 22 or higher. If all numbers are rolled equally often you will profit $\frac{n}{30} (22 + \cdots + 30) = n\frac{234}{30}$. He will win $\frac{n}{30} (1 + 2 + \cdots + 21) = n\frac{231}{30}$. If he chooses a number larger than you then you will win 22 or lower, which by a similar calculation shows that you will win more than you lose.

Comment: The intuition is nice, but unfortunately, I don't think it explains why choosing $22$ is optimal at all. Yes, it is true that choosing $22$ means that you will win more than your opponent does. However, how does this demonstrate that you can't do better by choosing, say, $21$ instead?

Comment: Well, since choosing 22 is a winning strategy, all other strategies that involve picking the same number everytime must be losing, since you allow your opponent to choose 22 (which is winning).

Comment: That does make things a little clearer, but isn't quite complete. For instance, if I choose $14$ first, the second player should choose $15$ to maximise their winnings. $22$ is no longer their winning strategy.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed that the second player plays optimally and thus only chooses a number one higher of one lower than the first number. However if you allow the second player to choose 22, you will always lose and therefore not choosing 22 is not optimal.

Comment: @TimDikland - This is a great proof, simple and on-point!  May I suggest you edit it to include your comments in the main answer?  One tiny missing piece in the explanation (which I'm sure you realize) might be that any strategy just split the expected winning $\frac{1+2+\cdots+30}{30} = 15.5$ among the two players, and what you have proved is that choosing 22 gives you more than half of the $15.5$ no matter what your opponent does.  So if the first player chooses anything else, the second player can do no worse than pick 22, which already gives the first player less than half of $15.5$.